# If $2 (a\cos x - \cos 2x) = 1$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

If $2 (a \cos x - \cos 2x) = 1$ for $x\in \mathbb R$ then find all possible real values of $a$.

I first expanded $\cos 2x$ then used quadratic equation inequalities for the domain $\cos x \in (-1,1)$ of $\cos x$ to get values of a which gave me $a\in (-\frac{3}{4},\frac{3}{4})$ but the answer is supposed to be $a\in (-\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2})$. Is my answer not correct if so can anyone verify the solution. If it is correct then too please give your approach.

Comment: A remark, `$\cos x$` looks better than `$cos x$`. Now, don't you also think that $\cos x$ looks better than $cos x$?

Comment: You answer does not look correct: it does not include $a=1$, for which solutions exist (i.e. $\cos x=1$ and $\cos x = 0$).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the intermediate steps. What was the quadratic inequality you obtained?

Comment: @SeanRoberson    And      $\text{\cos (x)}$ is still better

Comment: I tried it again and there was a simple calculation mistake $a \in (\frac{-3}{2},\frac{3}{2})$ was the correct answer. Sorry about that.but I would still appreciate if someone shows a diff approach

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici But many mathematical texts write $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ without parentheses enclosing the input variable. Is the preference for the parentheses influenced by programming languages?

Comment: @ryang That's historical notation which honestly is kind of terrible. Note that $\cos^2x  = (\cos x)^2$ but $\cos^{-1}x \ne \sec x$. $\cos^2 x$ meaning $\cos(\cos x)$ and $\cos(x)^2$ meaning $(\cos x)^2$ would be better, but $\cos^2 x = (\cos x)^2$ is too ingrained, and apparently then some people think you mean $\cos(x^2)$ when you write $\cos(x)^2$.

Comment: @ryang. May be this notation is prehistorical but at least it is clear. Then, why not to  write $\cos(a+b)$ as $\cos a+b$

Comment: @eyeballfrog 1. What has the $\cos^{-1}x \ne \sec x$ example got to do with input parentheses? 2. I dislike $\cos(x)^2$ due to the lack of consensus over how to read it, so the input parentheses here doesn't aid in this regard; either $\cos^2x$ or $(\cos x)^2$ is fine.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  1. I'm not against the input parentheses, just querying why you think using it is better even when there's no ambiguity. 2. Of *course* $\cos(a+b)$ ought to be written with the parentheses, just like $(2+3)\times7;$ the question was why you think $\sin(x)$ is necessarily better than $\sin x$ and is there perchance some influence from computing.

Comment: @ryang In $\cos^2 x$, the $^2$ represents multiplication, but in $\cos^{-1} x$, the $^{-1}$ represents *functional* inverse, not multiplicative inverse. We put up with this because it's standard at this point, but it's still inconsistent.

Comment: @eyeballfrog 1. This (tangential) discussion is about the preference for input parentheses `()` in something like `sin(x)`. Using input parentheses (like this: $\cos^2(x)$) doesn't actually disambiguate whether function composition or exponentiation is intended, which is a separate issue. 2. To be clear, I do not dislike input parentheses; but *I* would actually still write $(\cos(x))^2$ or $(\cos^2(x))$ instead of $\cos(x)^2,$ which I find jarring despite knowing its typical intended meaning. (On the other hand, I've never known anyone who writes $\cos^2x$ to mean function composition.)

Comment: @ryang. For me, it is not tangential at all. This is probably because I am $80^{++}$. I think that not writing the parentheses when I was a student would have been considered as much more serious than a sin; Basically, we agree. Cheers and thanks for the discussion. :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm actually under the impression (and eyeballfrog seems to suggest likewise) that the preference for using the input parentheses for trig functions is a modern preference (say, 50 years young?), but your input interestingly suggests otherwise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, note that $\cos x \in [-1,1]$, not $(-1,1)$.

Following your method, we get
$$
2(a\cos x - 2\cos^2 x + 1) = 1 \Longrightarrow  4\cos^2 x - 2a\cos x -1 = 0.
$$
Quadratic formula gives
$$
\cos x = \frac{2a \pm \sqrt{4a^2+16}}{8} = \frac{a\pm\sqrt{a^2+4}}{4}.
$$
For the positive solution, we have
$$
\frac{a + \sqrt{a^2+4}}{4}\le 1\Longrightarrow \sqrt{a^2+4} \le 4 - a\Longrightarrow a^2 + 4\le 16+a^2-8a\Longrightarrow a \le\frac{3}{2}.
$$
For the negative solution, we have
$$
\frac{a - \sqrt{a^2+4}}{4}\ge -1 \Longrightarrow 4 + a  \ge \sqrt{a^2+4} \Longrightarrow 16+8a+a^2\ge a^2+4\Longrightarrow a \ge -\frac{3}{2}.
$$
So the solution seems to be $a\in [-3/2,3/2]$ as expected. Perhaps you made an algebra error somewhere?

Comment: Yeah it was an algebra error, thanks.

Comment: Answer $a\in[-\frac32,\frac32]$ suggests that both solutions exists, but I don't see corresponding requirement in problem statement.